# Various Android Emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I've the default (comes with the SDK) and Samsung Galaxy Tab emulators in my SDK. I want to know what other third party (Motorola, LG, Sharp, etc) emulators are available, so that I can test my apps for more devices. Please provide the names with links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this link a while back. It goes pretty in-depth on how to set up the sizing and capabilities for many devices. These are just alternative AVDs that run in the default emulator, though, and it might not be exactly what you're looking for.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/

Comment: I don't know if this will answer Chromium's question, but I find it really useful! thanks :)

Comment: The galaxy Tab is also an alternative AVD

Answer (score 3):

The Motorola SDK addons (i.e. emulator images) are all available on the MOTODEV site (http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/).  You will need to register an account, but you can download images for all the shipping phones.  If you join the App Accelerator Program, you get early access to addons for unreleased products.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com). Its fast (faster than with Intel x86) with GPS and Battery support and comes with pre-rooted.